# Capturing photos in Salesforce1

Tags: salesforce1-app

While designing a Salesforce1 app that required associating photos with records, I found that the 1MB image limit for Rich Text Area fields prevents the use of smartphone camera photos (as opposed to photos taken previously) because they typically exceed 1MB. On iOS there is no option to reduce the image quality to a produce a smaller file.

While attachments or Chatter posts are an option, the ideal design for this app (a vinyl LP archiving database) benefits from having fields labelled Front Cover, Back Cover, Liner Notes, etc. And the best User Experience is being able to take pictures as you create the record rather than importing them afterwards. Additionally, it would be better to store smaller images to avoid file storage limits.

Any ideas for overcoming this limitation? I had hoped that the iOS email attachment function that allows you to choose various image quality/sizes would be available in Salesforce1 to control for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luke, you may give a try to [SharinPix](http://sharinpix.com) - **disclaimer, this is my app**

This specialized app for salesforce could be used to achieve so like this :

Adding an album to the objects

- Take picture to the camera under Salesforce1 adding image to the album
- Choose this image in the album and the menu command (Add To Rich Text)
- It makes a call to salesforce code (then you can do your magic here)
- it provides an URL for the image to be inserted with the wanted metrics (resolution, width, height, ...)

Coud that help?

Answer (score -1):

The "Upload File" LWC component takes care of it in Salesforce One (mobile version).
If this is used while building the Flow, then in mobile version it will take care of it AUTOMATICALLY.but please test it in mobile version as well.